# What's the BEST WAY to check (and do something) for a touch event in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a newbie question. I just started learning about libgdx and I'm a bit confused. I read the documentation/wiki, I followed some tutorials like the one from gamefromscratch and others and I still have a question.

What's the best way to check and do something for a touch/tap event?

I'm using Scenes and Actors and I found at least 4 ways (till now) of interacting with an Actor, let's say:

```
1) myActor.addListener(new ClickListener(){...});

2) myActor.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled); and putting the code in the act() method

3) verifying Gdx.input.isTouched() in the render() method

4) overriding touchDown, touchUp methods
```

Any help with some details and suggestions when to use one over the other, or what's the difference between them would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always been using the first method and I think from an OOP viewpoint, it's the "best" way to do it.

The second approach will not work. Whether you set an `Actor` to be touchable or not, `Actor.act(float)` will still be called whenever you do `stage.act(float)`. That means you would execute your code in every frame.

`Gdx.input.isTouched()` will only tell you that a touch event has happened *anywhere* on the screen. It would not be a good idea to try to find out *which* actor has been hit by that touch, as they are already able to determine that themselves (`Actor.hit()`).

I'm not sure where you'd override `touchDown` and `touchUp`. Actors don't have these methods, so I'm assuming you are talking about a standard `InputProcessor`. In this case you will have the same problem like with your 3rd approach.

So adding a `ClickListener` to the actors you want to monitor for these kind of events is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks @noone for your answer. Another follow-up question, let's say, it's related to this and I don't want to ask new question for this. 

What event listener would be the "best" or recommended to use for checking the touch/tap (I'm interested only for mobile devices, don't care about desktop): I could use InputListener() with touchDown() method, or I could use ClickListener() with clicked(). I guess they do the same thing on mobile apps, but just wondering if there's any difference in using them. Thanks again

Comment: Touch and click is the same, the only difference is that on mobile, there is no pointer that moves before a touchDown happens. `ClickListener` actually *is* an `InputListener`, but it it offers more functionality. Go with `ClickListener`.